# How to execute IF AND in a loop?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I want to execute **if and** in a loop.
The code runs when not in a loop. (When I run the code one by one it gives the result I want).

I use `ActiveCell` as reference since I will use this code on another sheet with a different location.

```vb
Sub cobalagi()
Dim a, b As Range
Set a = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)
Set b = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4)

For I = 1 To GetBaris
    If Left(a.Value, 8) = "KML/INV/" And b.Value = "Project - cost" Then
        ActiveCell.Value = "Inv"
    Else
        ActiveCell.Value = "Bukan Inv"
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next I
End Sub
```

The code for `GetBaris`.

```vb
Function GetBaris() As Long
    GetBaris = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Address, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Address).Rows.Count
End Function
```

The data and result of looping. First row is correct, but all the rest row should result in "Bukan Inv".
[image: here the data and result of looping. first row is correct, but all the rest row sould resulting "Bukan Inv"]

Comment: Instead of `For I = 1 To GetBaris`, could you try adding above the `for` this? `Dim vGetBaris as integer`. Under that, `vGetBaris = GetBaris()`. Then, change the `for` to `For I = 1 to vGetBaris` and see if that helps.

Comment: hello @zedfoxus thank you for responding, but it still don't work

Comment: This likely won't make a difference in your issue, but just so you know... `Dim a, b As Range` is not doing what you think. It's defining `a` as a `variant` and `b` as a `Range`. What you want is `Dim a As Range, b as Range`.

Comment: [Don't use select as part of your code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: thank you for the information, I'm still new at vba. I see many people do that, and also this code runs well (if not in a loop) so i think it works.. but i'll literate more to know about this, thank you @pgSystemTester

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve your issues. If you have to use select then you can, but the sub `runcobalagi` should work. The reason you were having issues is because you kept checking against the first row, and while you're selection was checking, your offset `a` and `b` remained the same.

Try this...

```
Sub cobalagi()

   Call runcobalagi(AcvtiveCell)
   'or Call runcobalagi(Range("A4"))

End Sub


Private Sub runcobalagi(theStartCell As Range)
   Const a As Long = 3
   Const b As Long = 4
   Dim i As Long
   
   With theStartCell
      For i = 0 To GetBaris - 1
         If Left(.Offset(i, a).Value, 8) = "KML/INV/" And .Offset(i, b).Value = "Project - cost" Then
            
            .Offset(i, 0).Value = "INV"
          Else
            .Offset(i, 0).Value "Bukan Inv"
         End If
      
      Next i
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Note the correction as of 1 minute ago from this comment...

Answer (score 0):

### Fill Column With `True` or `False` Depending on Two Conditions

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Cobalagi()
    
    ' Source
    
    ' Column 1
    Const sCol1 As String = "D"
    Const sCrit1 As String = "KML/INV/" ' begins with
    ' Column 2
    Const sCol2 As String = "E"
    Const sCrit2 As String = "Project - cost" ' is equal
    
    ' Destination
    Const dCol As String = "A"
    Const dTrue As String = "Inv"
    Const dFalse As String = "Bukan Inv"
    
    ' Both
    Const fRow As Long = 4
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Calculate the last non-empty row in column 1.
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, sCol1).End(xlUp).Row
    If lRow < fRow Then Exit Sub ' no data in row range
    
    Dim sString As String
    Dim r As Long
    Dim IsMatch As Boolean
    
    ' Loop through the rows.
    For r = fRow To lRow
        
        ' Check.
        
        ' Column 1
        sString = CStr(ws.Cells(r, sCol1).Value)
        If InStr(1, sString, sCrit1, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then ' begins with
            
            ' Column 2
            sString = CStr(ws.Cells(r, sCol2).Value)
            If StrComp(sString, sCrit2, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' is equal
                
                IsMatch = True

            'Else ' is not equal; do nothing i.e. 'IsMatch = False'
            End If
        
        'Else ' doesn't begin with; do nothing
        End If
        
        ' Write result.
        If IsMatch Then
            ws.Cells(r, dCol).Value = dTrue
            IsMatch = False
        Else
            ws.Cells(r, dCol).Value = dFalse
        End If
    
    Next r
            
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Cobalagi is done.", vbInformation

End Sub
```